# bash variable expansion piped to ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I can't get my head around how to declare / refer to these variables in a shell script.

Given the contents of `commands_to_execute_on_remote.sh` as:

```
for c in 1 2 3 4 5
do
    supervisorctl restart broadcast-server-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-${c}
done
```

Where `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is declared as an environment variable on the local machine...

When I'm running this from a local machine as, e.g.:

```
cat commands_to_execute_on_remote.sh | ssh user@123.456.789
```

How do I refer to those variables in order that, by the time the script is piped to the remote box, `$ENVIRONMENT_NAME` is populated with the actual value but `$c` is - obviously - a loop counter within the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the commands in a separate file is an unnecessary complication.

```
ssh user@123.45.67.89 <<____EOF
    for c in 1 2 3 4 5; do
        supervisorctl restart broadcast-server-${ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-\$c
    done
____EOF
```

Notice how you want `$c` to be evaluated in the remote `ssh` shell (so you need to escape it from your local shell) while `$ENVIRONMENT_NAME` gets expanded by your local shell before the command line is sent to the remote server.

If you insist on putting the script snippet in a file, someething like

```
sed "s/[$][{]ENVIRONMENT_NAME[}]/$ENVIRONMENT_NAME/" commands_to_execute_on_remote.sh |
ssh user@132.45.67.89
```

allows for that (and avoids the ugly [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html)).  (If you remove the technically unnecessary braces, you need to adjust the regex; if `ENVIRONMENT_NAME` could contain a slash, use a different separator like `"s%...%...%"`.)

Comment: You should probably avoid using uppercase for your private variable names, too, but I have not attempted to fix that here.